# Issue with hebrew

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, hebrew

I am having issues using hebrew with mysql and PHP, i have already tried this:

the db collation has to be `utf8_general_ci`.

the collation of the table with hebrew has to be utf8_general_ci
in my php connection script i put

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

in my xhtml head tag i put 
after selecting the db in the connection script i put

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

And it is still not working. In phpmyadmin i can see the hebrew characters but when i display them in php all i see is "?????"
If anyone could help me that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

In your html page

1. Under `<head>` tage, add  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

At the time of mysql insert use `utf8_encode` & when show data try to use `utf8_decode`

Comment: Well i did the <meta> still shows question marks, and when i add the utf_decode it doesn't display anything

Comment: At the time of insert you need to use the url_encode() then only url_decode() will work.

Comment: 1.what is the character set of your database  or table? 2.At the time of insertion did you use url_encode()?

Comment: char set database and table: utf8_general_ci. and i inserted from phpmyadmin

Comment: Please try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: It says to Specify the utf8mb4 character set on all tables and text columns in your database.
and i do not see "utf8mb4" in the list